# Dynamically create a iframe using reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to dynamically create  iframe witch a specific url and className after click on the button. 
I start using react and I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special:

```
var Iframer = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return <iframe src="https://www.google.com" className="my-iframe" />
    }
})

React.render(<Iframer />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mt6dfw4d/1/

Comment: you need to give more detail, but basically just show or hide the iframe component above based on the state you would set after the click event.